# i Got error when i try to upload image to strapi Using flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, strapi

[image]

I tried to upload an image to Strapi using postman, but I got stuck with the following message:
"statusCode": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "An internal server error occurred"

Comment: try logging the error https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/logging.html

Comment: server error, share more info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is add new Line in body source : users-permissions